# Schengen visa allows visiting London

Tags: schengen, london

Does a multiple entry Schengen visa issued from the Italian embassy allow you to visit London once you are already in Italy or any Schengen area country? Or do I need to get a separate visa to the UK before travelling?

Answer (score 2):

The UK is not in the Schengen area. The countries that are colored in blue in this map:

[image]

(green is for countries that are legally bound to join)

So the answer to your first question is **no**. As for your second question...  whether or not you need a Visa for the UK [depends on your country of origin](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa).

Comment: Answer to the question is *"**no**, Schengen visa does not allow visiting London"*.

Comment: There was a secondary question in the OP's question: *Or do I need to get a separate visa to the UK before travelling?*